# How can I click on an expand button based on criteria using another column with Python and Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Below is a sample of my script. I am trying to test each row of a column on a site for "World Total". If "World Total" is in this column, then I want to click the expandable button in the same row in the column to the left. This then expands the column and the next "World Total" row will be much lower down. i.e. I have changing XPATHS and I am trying to figure out how to dynamically expand the row when it say world total. Any thoughts?

```
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UltraWebTab1__ctl1_grdExpressQuery_GridView1"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]')))
    all_rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UltraWebTab1__ctl1_grdExpressQuery_GridView1"]/tbody/tr')
    country = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UltraWebTab1__ctl1_grdExpressQuery_GridView1"]/tbody/tr/td[4]')
    expand = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UltraWebTab1__ctl1_grdExpressQuery_GridView1"]/tbody/tr/td[3]')
    
    for x in range(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UltraWebTab1__ctl1_grdExpressQuery_GridView1"]/tbody/tr'))):
        if driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UltraWebTab1__ctl1_grdExpressQuery_GridView1"]/tbody/tr[' + str(x) + ']/td[4]') == "World Total":
            driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UltraWebTab1__ctl1_grdExpressQuery_GridView1"]/tbody/tr[' + str(x) + ']/td[3]/input').click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going a different route as I had issues arise with the staleness of elements. I knew how many clicks we would be looking for so I used a (5,4,3,2,1) variation of this formula to dynamically select depending on the rows:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UltraWebTab1__ctl1_grdExpressQuery_GridView1"]/tbody/tr[' + str(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UltraWebTab1__ctl1_grdExpressQuery_GridView1"]/tbody/tr')) - 1) + ']/td[3]/input').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work with some minor changes -

1. Find elements - returns a collection of elements. so you have to use find_element if you need to find a specific element.
2. text method returns the text with in the element.
3. Use try & except to handle the selenium exception ( if the element is not found )
4. X index starts from 0 by default. you can initialize to 1 depending on your x path.

Code should look like this,

```
myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UltraWebTab1__ctl1_grdExpressQuery_GridView1"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]')))
all_rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UltraWebTab1__ctl1_grdExpressQuery_GridView1"]/tbody/tr')
country = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UltraWebTab1__ctl1_grdExpressQuery_GridView1"]/tbody/tr/td[4]')
expand = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UltraWebTab1__ctl1_grdExpressQuery_GridView1"]/tbody/tr/td[3]')  
x=1
for x in range(len(all_rows )):
    try:
        if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UltraWebTab1__ctl1_grdExpressQuery_GridView1"]/tbody/tr[' + str(x) + ']/td[4]').text == "World Total":
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UltraWebTab1__ctl1_grdExpressQuery_GridView1"]/tbody/tr[' + str(x) + ']/td[3]/input').click()
                                
    except NoSuchElementException:
          #Do something here
```

Comment: I get the error: TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: See updated answer - we have to use length property of the list object